# IOS 11 XCODE 9: Archive errors Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Tags: ios11

I am trying to create an archive for a XCODE 9 app using NFC core and getting errors (see images) that I cant figure out having tried many settings. We are using the new NFC Core framework in the app and all works perfectly when running on devices etc - just wont create a archive so we can add to TestFight...

[image: Archive errors generated]

[image]

[image: Trying to upload archive and apple not allow beta code]

Here is a screen shot of me having changed the scheme for Archive to debug, but with no different results unfortunately.

[image: Scheme > Archive changed to debug]

Comment: I have tried reducing the architecture and architecture validation down to armv7 and still get the same errors but obviously stating Undefined symbols for armv7

Comment: Have you tried setting Archive's build configuration to debug in the target's scheme? I know it is not an "answer" to your problem, but it could get you through...

Comment: Thanks @carles - happy to give a go but I can't find the obvious place to change this so a screen shot or explanation might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in my opinion there might not be the release versions of this symbols, it is an option, and if it worked while testing you might have a go compiling with Debug settings the archived version too:

Click on your target scheme settings:

[image]

Click on edit scheme:

[image]

Select Archive, and then change the Build Configuration to Debug:

[image]

Then you can have a go again at archiving... The side effect might be that the executable will be bigger... Let me know if it works :-)

Comment: Ah nice try, but I did not get different results when I changed the target scheme for archive to debug.  I will try and post an image somewhere so can see that I have done it OK.  I cleaned the project and rebuilt before archiving also. I have found some posts about frameworks not being in bitcode and they have to archived themselves first before the whole project can be archived, but any answers relating to that have not worked when I tried them and as CoreNFC is part of the apple framework not even sure you can do that - if that makes any sense.

Comment: Try turning off bitcode on your project then, go to Build Settings on the project view, and turn off Enable bitcode for your target... If you have already tried this the only option might be to manually install the test applications on the devices with the cable and XCode...

Comment: Well by turning off bitcode it has successfully created the archive - nice one.    I assume you would normally want to use bitcode, but good for me to see if I can upload to connect and distribute via TestFlight :-) Thanks for all your help - I will report back if all goes well.

Comment: After all that it would seems Apple do not let you upload archives created by Beta versions of XCODE which obviously our which has to use Swift 4 and XCODE 9 for CoreNFC does.  Should be a way and will explore but the archive created seems to be OK otherwise... see screen show in original post about complaining. I did load up and tried to create archive in XCODE 8 but not happy doing that.

Comment: @ZipNFC You shouldn't be encountering the error regarding beta software if you're using Xcode9b2 and your computer is on **Sierra**. Also, be sure you're not using a toolchain from Swift.org.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to update this post as since upgrading to XCODE 9 Beta 3 all these issues have gone away.  I can now Archive with bitcode on and have successfully uploaded to ITUNES connect for publishing externally as a TestFlight without any code changes at all..

Thanks for all the help to move it on but I could not get on TestFlight as threw up all sorts of issues and all fixed with the latest build cam along - thanks Apple!

Comment: Great, nice to hear!

Comment: We have had no problems since then so not sure it is the same problem you are having...